# Model suggestion alternative to categorical regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, learning

I am developing a model framework in the context of online marketing: the dependent variable is purchase, the independent variables includes a mix of continuous (e.g., impressions, ad spend) and categorical variables (e.g., day of the week, channel).

One of the categorical variable is creative which has about 20 different designs. The goal of the model is to measure which design is most effective in terms of driving the purchase.

I know a standard procedure would be using a mixed variable regression which convert the creative variable into dummies.  The regression fit was not satisfying given the p value and R square. My suspect is the data does not meet the regression requirement's of normal distribution and the relationship is non-linear.

I have considered other modeling techniques such as SVM and RF. The challenge with those models are that in order to get an effect for each level in the creative variable, I would have to convert the creative variable into dummy variables. I am not sure if this is a plausible approach.

If anyone can point me to some model framework that would be great. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have you prepared some visualizations of your data? Plotting the data points should always be the first step, this helps to gain insight into your data. A trivial pair-plot ([in R e.g. `pairs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/pairs)) could be a first step.

Next some comments on your approach with a mixed effect model: You say that you expect the relationship to be nonlinear, so I am wondering whether you have tried some nonlinear basis functions in your linear model? Your data visualizations might give you some clues as to what might work.

And if your errors are indeed not normal, there are generalized linear models (in R e.g. [the `glm` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/glm), [`glmm` for mixed effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmm/glmm.pdf), or [`glmnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) for regularization) that could help with this issue. Some [GAM regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) might be beneficial, too.

If you want to leave the realm of linear models for sure, there are many possibilities to consider next, e.g. some nonlinear fitting with [`nls()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/nls) or some Bayesian approaches with e.g. [rstan](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/stan_nlmer.html).

Once you tried all those and other model-driven approaches and you are not yet satisfied, you could explore those data-driven models like [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest), as you have already mentioned. [Deep neural networks](https://pytorch.org/) also fall into this category. Given enough data, they are often very good at predicting but don't give much insight.

You mentioned concerns w.r.t. the one-hot encoding for SVM or RF, but I don't see any problems here, this is a plausible approach.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you so much for your insight. I will explore the data more following your suggestions. I have an additional question. So the real goal of my model is to compare the effect of the same design across different years (i.e., 2019-2022). For example, under the creative variable, there are 9 designs for 2019, 11 designs for 2020, and so on. Some designs ran every year while others only appeared in selected years. I know that I can run 4 regressions with one for each year and compare the coefficients. Are there any models can achieve that by using all four years' data in one model?